# What is the best way (in terms of performance and accuracy) to perform value estimation/prediction?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, cart, k-nearest-neighbour

How do I predict the value of an item given its features and attributes? What is the best approach to this regression problem, in terms of performance as well as accuracy? And how do I process this large range of data?

---

**The Data:** Each item has an `id` and various attributes. Most items share the same attributes, however there are a few special items with items specific attributes. An example would look something like this:

```py
item = {
  "item_id": "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  "tier_upgrades": 1,  # (0-1)
  "damage_upgrades": 15,  # (0-15)
     ...
  "stat_upgrades": 5  # (0-5)
}
```

I'm not quite sure if this is considered categorical or quantitative data, each "upgrade"/attribute has a level, represented by a number. It is possible for them to be placed into categories/buckets based on their level.

**The relationship between any attribute and the value of the item is linear; if the level of an attribute is increased, so is the value, and vise versa. However, an upgrade at level 1 is not necessarily 1/2 of the value of an upgrade at level 2; the value added for each level increase is different.** All attributes are capped at a certain integer, however it is not constant for all attributes. As an item gets higher levels of upgrades, they are also more likely to have other high level upgrades, which is why the price starts to have a steeper slope at upgrade level 10+. This may cause problems for regression and other solutions because it’s just adding noise.

[image: linear relationship]

**Collected Data:** I've collected a bunch of data on the prices of these items with various different combinations of these upgrades. **Note: The value/cost of each upgrade is not constant between items, nor is the price of the item without upgrades.**

As far as pricing goes, high tier, low drop chance items are usually going to be priced based on pure demand/supply, however other middle tier items that have a certain cost to unlock/buy will usually settle for a bit over the cost to acquire. Prices of these items fluctuate a bit throughout daily cycles/updates/new metas/etc, however they are usually pretty stable. The value of items is purely based on the cost to buy/acquire the base item and the upgrades/attributes that they have.

**Problems with the data:** Overlapping data and attributes with a range from 0 to 1. As shown below, almost all points where `tier_upgrades == 0` overlap with the bottom half of `tier_upgrades == 1`, which causes problems for any type of regression. In addition, this specific attribute only ranges from 0 - 1, making regression impossible (afaik).
[image: tier_upgrades vs price, showing overlapping data]

---

**Attempts made so far:** I've tried linear, polynomial, and multivariable regression, using a KNN, and tried a custom algorithm which iterates through each feature and finds the average price in the distribution of items with the same feature. I have not tried tree regression methods as I feel like they would be too slow. However, maybe there is one I don’t know about, so let me know.

---

**Regression:** It works, but with a high amount of error. Due to the nature of the data I'm working with, many of the features are either a 1 or 0 and/or overlap a lot. From my understanding, this creates a lot of noise in the model and degrades the accuracy of it. I'm also unsure of how well it would scale to multiple items, since each is valued independent of each other. Aside from that, in theory, regression should work because different attributes affect the value of an item linearly.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import linear_model

x = df.drop("id", axis=1).drop("adj_price", axis=1)
y = df.drop("id", axis=1)["adj_price"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=69)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)

y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
mae = np.mean(np.absolute(y_pred - y_test))
print(f"RMSE: {rmse} MAE: {mae}")
```

---

**K-Nearest Neighbors:** This has also worked, but not all the time. Sometimes I run into issues where I don't have enough data for one item, which then forces it to choose a very different item, throwing off the value completely. In addition, there are some performance concerns here, as it is quite slow to generate an outcome. This example is written in JS, using the [nearest-neighbor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nearest-neighbor) package. Note: The price is not included in the item object, however I add it when I collect data, as it is the price that gets paid for the item. The price is only used to find the value after the fact, it is not accounted for in the KNN search, which is why it is not in `fields`.

```js
const nn = require("nearest-neighbor");

var items = [
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 1,
    damage_upgrades: 15,
    stat_upgrades: 5,
    price: 1800000
  },
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 0,
    damage_upgrades: 0,
    stat_upgrades: 0,
    price: 1000000
  },
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 0,
    damage_upgrades: 8,
    stat_upgrades: 2,
    price: 1400000
  },
];
 
var query = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 1,
  damage_upgrades: 10,
  stat_upgrades: 3
};

var fields = [
  { name: "item_id", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.word },
  { name: "tier_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
  { name: "damage_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
  { name: "stat_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
];
 
nn.findMostSimilar(query, items, fields, function(nearestNeighbor, probability) {
  console.log(query);
  console.log(nearestNeighbor);
  console.log(probability);
});
```

---

**Averaged distributions:** Below is a box chart showing the distribution of prices for each level of `damage_upgrades`. This algorithm will find the average price where the `attribute == item[attribute]` for each attribute, and then find the mean. This is a relatively fast way to calculate the value, much faster than using a KNN. However, there is often too big of a spread in a given distribution, which increases the error. Another problem with this is if there is not an equal(ish) distribution of items in each set, it also increases the error. However, the main problem is that items with max upgrades except for a few will be placed in the same set, further disrupting the average, because there is a spread in the value of items. An example:

```py
low_value = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 0,
  damage_upgrades: 1,
  stat_upgrades: 0,
  price: 1_100_000
}
# May be placed in the same set as a high value item:
high_value = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 0,
  damage_upgrades: 15,
  stat_upgrades: 5,
  price: 1_700_000
}
# This spread in each set is responsible for any inaccuracies in the prediction, because the algorithm does not take into account any other attributes/upgrades.
```

[image: damage_upgrades price distribution]

Here is the Python code for this algorithm. `df` is a regular dataframe with the `item_id`, `price`, and the attributes.

```py
total = 0
features = {
 'tier_upgrades': 1,
 'damage_upgrades': 15,
 'stat_upgrades': 5,
}
for f in features:
  a = df[df[f] == features[f]]
  avg_price = np.mean(a["adj_price"])
  total += avg_price

print("Estimated value:", total / len(features))
```

If anyone has any ideas, please, let me know!

Comment: tree based methods are probably worth a shot here. I think people like xgboost these days (but probably other commenters will have more up-to-date suggestions). Trees can help you with determining variable importance as well.

Comment: I was just going to say the first hammer I would take to the nut would be a random forest.  I wouldn't just look at regression though.  I would also use R/Boruta and look at variable importance.  The h2o.ai tool has something their (non-technical sales) calls auto-ml, which is really a grid of fits using several tools (xgboost/gbm if installed, random forest, mlp, gan, lm, ...)  It is a decent first try that doesn't give final results but can help you get started.  To me it looks like a zero and one padded exponential distribution, so finite mixture model might do some good.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks for the suggestion! I tried to get h2o.ai to work, unfortunately it just won't train on my data and will crash or just hang there forever. Are there any alternatives? (I'm working on implementing Boruta into my program)

Comment: I'm really surprised about that.  Are you in R or in Python?  There are dozens of alternatives, but H2O.ai is open source, Java (so it runs everywhere) and has some very very clever tricks in the way it discretizes and handles CART ensembles.  XGBoost isn't bad on its own.  There are Genetic Algorithm tools that can do the job, but I like to use them to make very simple but still effective tools for use on very small footprint hardware.

Comment: @EngrStudent Oh my bad, I was originally looking at H2O Cloud. Training a model with AutoML through their Flow web UI now (running on my local machine). I guess their cloud service doesn't like any big data. Also, do you think it will be able to split values automatically based on the item id? Because I've noticed while training with mixed data (with items that cannot have any of these attributes), these items are highly overpriced when predicting, even though all attributes are 0. I assumed it would predict around the average price, but idk what's going on here.

Comment: Also, do you think that these attributes are considered categorical? They were all automatically labeled as numerical except for the item id, where that one is definitely categorical. However, they only have a limited range, usually from 0-1 or 0-5, so I was thinking that maybe that would help it predict?

Comment: One of the things to be careful about is having input variables that falsely indicate the category. Unique identifiers that are not implicit to the data are usually a bad idea. You probably do not want to include those as input variables. Let it process the range and tell you. It has excellent handling of the difference between nominal, multinomial, ordinal, and continuous. Rule of thumb is that if you throw away one of the inputs and it goes from being infinitely perfect to being only moderate fit, then maybe that variable was not a good variable to have.

Comment: In well over 20 years of work I’ve only seen the real world give 4 or 5 9’s accuracy, 3 times. 99.9% or more Is an indication that one of your variables is cheating and communicating the answer in a way that’s unrealistic.